# Approved Norwegian Bible translations within Catholicism?

Tags: catholicism, bible, bible-translation, canon-law

Which modern-day Norwegian Bible translations have been explicitly approved by the Vatican or other authorities authorized to make such an approval?

The Catholic translation of the New Testament by Erik Gunnes (1969) is widely used, and I have read that the newest translation (2011) from the Norwegian Bible Society (NO2011) has been accepted with a few changes, and NO1930 also appears to have been accepted to some degree after Vatican II. Still, regarding other translations existing which there are fewer written traces of within Norwegian Catholicism, e.g. NO1978/85, or Norsk Bibel 1988/2007 (which is concordant and close to NO1930), I wonder if [canon 825](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib3-cann822-833_en.html) (or other sources) permits, or advice against, the use of these.

The general advice of not using any translation from non-Catholic sources resulted in Offerdahl's work and its ammendment prior to Vatican II, but both this and Gunnes contain only the New Testament. It is noteworthy how the former in a standard way refers to OT passages while at the same time it leaves no doubt that any Norwegian or Danish translation of the Old Testament in existence at the time was forbidden for a Catholic to read.

Comment: Normally the Norwegian (Scandinavian) National Conference of Catholic Bishops will have this type of information on their national website.

Comment: I have not found anything online covering the question. As for the Nordic Conference of Catholic Bishops, it should perhaps be in this (https://www.katolsk.no/dokumenter/norden) list of documents, but nothing suggests they cover the topic in question.

Comment: Unfortunately I not understand the language. But might be able to ask a priest friend for you?

Comment: There's this article: https://www.katolsk.no/tro/tema/tradisjon/artikler/norske-bibeloversettelser-fra-reformasjonstiden-til-i-dag-2013-en-oversikt but I can't imagine that everything examined is actually permitted for use at all, let alone merely in private.